# Bad : modifier in $ (/). appears whenever after login and creating a new screen in Linux

Tags: linux

The following error always appears whenever after login and creating a new screen in Linux :

```
Bad : modifier in $ (/).
```

Recently I added some paths and I don't know if it is related.

For the paths, I remember I added stuff to `$PATH` and `.bashrc`.

How could I correct it so it won't appear again?

Thank you!

Comment: We don't know if it's related either. Could you add what you changed to the question please?

Comment: “You added some paths“ means you added stuff to `$PATH`? Did you change your `.bashrc`? Can you post your `.profile` and `.bashrc`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805839/bad-modifier-in

Comment: Wild guess: you added a path with `$` in it, and the shell interprets `$` as a special character.

Comment: I remember I added stuff to $PATH and .bashrc.
How could I view my .profile and .bashrc?
Mark, I have viewed that post and tried to something like : setenv PATH ${PATH}:/, but didn't work.

Comment: What files (aside from .bashrc) have you recently edited? .cshrc, .login, anything in the /etc directory?

Answer (score 3):

You do not use `bash` as your shell, but `(t)csh`:

```
> csh
% PATH="${PATH:/blah}"
Bad : modifier in $ (/).
```

If you want to use `bash` instead, you can probably run `chsh` or ask your system administrator to change it for you.

In `bash`, if you were to misalign the `:` and place it within the curly braces `{` `}` it would mean that a *modifier* is to be applied to the variable. In `csh` the curly braces are not needed to apply a modifier and you would actually *need* to add curly braces if you do *not* want the `:` to signal that a modifier is following it.

Comment: Is this a guess or a fact?  It's hard to tell.

Comment: @Wildcard `bash` has very different error messages; it would say: 'syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/blah")'. I clarified my answer some more.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to escape ':'. So, your cshrc file should look like,

```
setenv PATH $PATH\:/path/to/add
```

After this, you can do,

```
source ~/.cshrc
```

to apply changes to the current terminal. It will automatically be applied the next time you open a new terminal.

Comment: A more correct syntax in (t)csh would be `setenv PATH ${PATH:q}:/path/to/add`. Or better `set path = ($path:q /path/to/add)` or even better in `tcsh`: `set -f path = ($path:q /path/to/add)` to keep the elements unique.